# Account import into gmail - is it considered safe?

Tags: email, gmail, outlook

From my Gmail account / settings, I can import another mailing account (for example a Microsoft Exchange account).

Then Google asks for my personal Microsoft Exchange password **(! this is not very "OAuth")**.

[image]

After the setup is complete, I can read and send emails impersonating my Microsoft Outlook account from Gmail.

I guess this as safe as my Google account... but **would you advise it for an organization?**

**Should we allow our users to configure the company's Outlook account into their personal Gmail?**

I guess not...

Comment: What would be the use-case? If I wanted to access my personal e-mails at work, I can log into gmail on the web. And if I want my work emails on my private phone - not that I ever want that - I could simply add an outlook account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Company emails should not be stored on personal accounts or devices. There are data protection/privacy issues, as well as issues around corporate control over data.

By doing this, the company loses control over the email.

Email is used for many different things, including passing files and using it as a de facto file store. To pass all that data to a personal data store is often considered a breach of data (specifics are up to the relevant data protection regulation the company is subject to).

So, it's not about Gmail. It's about the appropriate use of email in general. Gmail could be the most secure email system on the planet, and using it would still be inappropriate.